# jQuery UI - Is it really this messy

Tags: jquery-ui

I render a page from the server (an admin intranet app) then I want jQuery UI it and keep things consistent with the selected jquery ui theme.

Take for example buttons

```
<button class="do-something">Logout</button>
```

The jQuery UI documentation say that one should not apply ui-state-default and 37 other CSS classes manually (at server render time), but on a initial render one should call `$(selector).button()` where selector maybe just 'button' or '.nice-button' etc..

This seems a bit smelly to me but I suppose the fine grain control make sense given its not intending to be as high-level as ExtJS or Sproutcore etc..

Then I thought what about an icon button I'd thought `<button class="do-something ui-icon-arrow-e">Logout</button>` when calling `.button()` it would check for presence of such class and render accordingly. However it seems one has to do `button(icons { pri: 'blah'}})`. Yikes.

Am I approaching it wrong? it seems like a code smell here mixing a lot JavaScript statements related purely to rendering outside the html? I haven't even considered stuff injected later via ajax etc..

Then I want to have a panel with heading like an accordion, I ended up having to dump about 93 CSS classes onto a div and h3 to get things consistent. I then created my own extension jQuery $ fn extension `.crmPanel()` which was basically `parent.addClass` 43 and `parent.children('h3:first').addClass()` 53 times. Seems messy

How are people using jQuery UI in intranet apps, or are you just purely using the element and doing the others bit manually?

(note divide any quantitative figures related to number of CSS classes by 4)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI CSS Framework gives a nice base for some of the UI elements such as Tabs, Dialogs etc. We have found it lacking and therefore would usually add another CSS file to enhance standard CSS with some CSS3 effects, add typography and Grid System.

The result looks like this:
http://agiletoolkit.org/intro/engage

and although it's still based on jQuery UI theme it does not look like that.

When it comes to buttons, we sometimes use the jQuery but sometimes use CSS. In that particular example, CSS is used, in other cases (selector).button() is used:

http://codepad.agiletoolkit.org/buttonpushing.html?b=devel

In regards to panels and layouts, compared to ExtJS, jQuery does almost nothing to help out. Besides, I'm not fan of JS-controlled layouts since they are slow and jittery. I think CSS is a way to go.